# cannot import name objectify

Tags: lxml, python-2.7

I want to use lxml python library. I installed it with pip tool on python2.7

```
pip install lxml
```

when I open python shell interpreter and write

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name objectify
```

this exception is raised. I also tried to install older versions 3.2, 2.2.8 but the same problem rises. don't know what to do

Answer (score 2):

Use easy_install

`easy_install lxml`

`>>> from lxml import objectify`

Comment: I love how (re)installing lxml still fixes this issue, 8 years later.

Comment: How will the same work on AWS Glue? I've given this wheel file as path: 
lxml-4.8.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl. Its downloading but failing in "from lxml import objectify" part. Can't install manually inside a managed service like Glue, any help?

Answer (score 0):

From PyCharm you can install lxml 3.4.2 and it works.