# AWS Glue ImportError: cannot import name objectify from lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, aws-glue, lxml.objectify

Environment: Glue 3.0, Python 3.7

Downloaded and added wheel file in Glue's Python library path of lxml-4.8.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl which I downloaded from pypi.

I am trying to run:

```
from lxml import objectify
```

But am getting the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'objectify' from 'lxml' (/tmp/lxml-4.8.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl/lxml/**init**.py)

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659793/cannot-import-name-objectify) and the likes of it, but can't install manually inside a managed service like Glue.

Any help?

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to do a whl file?   ie why not add the `--additional-python-modules` key with a value of `lxml` as a Job Parameter?

Comment: I can do that, but it still would pull the same package internally and install, isn't?

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't confident your whl file would work, but I checked it and it does work.  So you could do just `lxml` or you could do something like `s3://my-bucket/lxml-4.8.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl`  Both values should work with `--additional-python-modules`

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes Bob, it worked with additional python modules, but the exact same version when kept in S3 is failing. So, I continued with the prior one. You can write it as an answer and I'll accept it as working. Thanks for your help!